# how to write loop in Ognl?

Tags: java, ognl

I'd like to reimplement the following Java code with Ognl:

```
while((s=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)  System.out.println(s);
```

but I have no idea, could you give me point?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OGNL is Object Graph Navigation Language and not a full fledged programming language. You can use ognl along with other technologies like Struts2 tags in a JSP and implement a corresponding while loop

from wikipedia

> It is aimed to be used in Java EE applications with taglibs as expression language.